# ReactJS stateless component parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stateless

What is the preferred/correct choice for ReactJS stateless component's parameter? Is it props or list out all prop names?

Choice 1:

```
const Checkbox = props => {}
```

Choice 2:

```
const Checkbox = ({name, value}) => {}
```

Comment: It's upto you. no any performance difference. just related to coding style.

Answer (score 0):

There is not incorrect choice here.

If you have a few props only, like in your example `name` and `value` you can destructure them. If you have 10+ props, I think it's better to use just `props` and then work with them in the component body, just because of the visual style.

Answer (score 0):

Way way you want to use you component depends on how your component is implemented and its a matter of personal preference as well. The functional component is passed as `props` as argument post which you may prefer to use it as it is or destructure it

> Choice 1: const Checkbox = props => {}

Most often you may use the above method when there are too many props that you wish to use or pass all of them down to the child component

> Choice 2: const Checkbox = ({name, value}) => {}

The above pattern is where you destructure `name` and `value` from props. You may choose to do so when you only need to use `name` and `value` out of all the props passed

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is a preferred/correct  way to do it 
**i think the rule of thumb should be the number of parameters.**
if you got more then 6 parameters the code starts looking messy 
you can always use the object destructuring assignment inside your component

Answer (score 0):

the choice is yours , both ways are good , use based on component

1) you can use when component is big (use more props):

> Choice 1: const Checkbox = props => {}

2) you can use when component is small , and required 2 or 3 props

> Choice 2: const Checkbox = ({name, value}) => {}

there is no standard when use which one , it is all upto you , but when component is big use choice-1 which makes code cleaner.